# Initial conditions in multi-state Tesla Coil circuit

Tags: passive-networks, resonance, tesla-coil

Half a year ago I posted [this quesion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/363927/change-of-frequency-in-a-capacitor-when-switch-closes) about a Tesla Coil resonant circuit which got an amazing answer that helped me understand the resonant frenquency of such circuit.

Now I've returned to that problem and I want to know what happens in the following scenario. I will not post the values of the components since I just want a theoretical answer to understand better this kind of circuits, but I can say that the relation
$$L_1C_1=L_2C_2$$
is fulfilled. The circuit is shown below:
[image]

The capacitor `C1` is the only one charged. It releases its energy and the circuit starts resonating. The voltage across `C2` has the following form:

[image]

which can be translated in the mathematical expression: 
$$137898 \cdot (\cos(978300t) − \cos(1081600t))$$

Now, the switch `Sw1` opens and `Sw2` closes at the same time. Then, the circuit that (I think) results is:[image]

My questions are:

1. Would the value of `Vmax` at Figure 3 be determined by the value of `vSw2(t)` at the instant when switch `Sw2` closes and `Sw1` opens?
2. Is it true that, as one of the coupled inductors is in an open-circuit, given that `Sw1` is open, the initial conditions at inductor `L2` are 0? In other words, is the circuit that I've drawn in Figure 3 accurate?
3. Since there are no resistive elements at circuit from Figure 1, mathematically it seems correct that the equation of the voltage `vSw2(t)` has only cosines, but in reality the voltage would converge to 0 due to the internal resistances of the components, right?

Comment: It looks wrong, as the left side arcs open with no resonant circuit in theory and  charges up the cap to some DC V after successive switches  The arc is not a voltage source but rather and negative resistance to a charge dump. Current rises as voltage collapses.   This is what you have http://tinyurl.com/unqp4ax

Comment: or here http://tinyurl.com/rafw3m9  as you can see, unless you define values you dont get the same thing